# How to link and compile a C++ project for Linux using CMake? (Adapting CMakeLists.txt)

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

**Context:** I want to make a GameClient, GameServer, and custom library (which both Client and Server use) cross platform for Linux, Windows & MacOS. Server and Client both depend on various libraries I prefer linking statically, and headers. I heard I could do this by wrapping my 3 currently VisualStudio developed projects into a CMake environment, so I started by making CMakeLists.txt's for Server and Shared lib, which are the simplest and have fewer library dependencies.

**Question:** How can I adapt these CMakeLists.txt's (currently building on and for Windows), so I can choose if I want to compile for Windows or Linux (preferably from Windows)?

Shared Lib CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(MORPH_Server VERSION 1.0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

set(SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES TRUE) #Link to statically
set(SFML_DIR "C:/libraries/SFML/SFMLx64SourceAndCompile")
find_package(SFML 2.5.1 COMPONENTS system network REQUIRED)

add_library(MORPH_Shared_Functions)
target_sources(MORPH_Shared_Functions
               PRIVATE Transform.cpp
               PRIVATE World.cpp
               PRIVATE Player.cpp
               PRIVATE PropsData.cpp
               PRIVATE Prop.cpp
               PRIVATE udp_network_manager.cpp
               PRIVATE utility_functions.cpp
               )

target_link_libraries(MORPH_Shared_Functions 
                      sfml-system #Basically already found sfml modules and their dependencies (find-package)
                      sfml-network
                      )

target_include_directories(MORPH_Shared_Functions
                           PRIVATE C:/libraries/SFML/SFML-2.5.1/include
                           PRIVATE C:/libraries/GLM/glm
                           PRIVATE C:/libraries/CEREAL
                           )
```

Server CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(MORPH_Server VERSION 1.0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

configure_file(CmakeConfig.h.in CmakeConfig.h)

set(SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES TRUE) #Link to statically
set(SFML_DIR "C:/libraries/SFML/SFMLx64SourceAndCompile")
find_package(SFML 2.5.1 COMPONENTS system network REQUIRED)

add_executable(MORPH_Server)
target_sources(MORPH_Server
               PRIVATE Main.cpp 
               PRIVATE Game.cpp
               PRIVATE CommandManager.cpp
               PRIVATE ServerPlayer.cpp
               PRIVATE ServerProp.cpp
               PRIVATE ServerWorldState.cpp
               PRIVATE UDP_Server_CS.cpp
               )
add_library(MORPH_Shared_Functions STATIC IMPORTED)

set_target_properties(MORPH_Shared_Functions PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION C:/Users/dylan/Desktop/MORPH/MORPH_Shared_Functions/Build/Debug/MORPH_Shared_Functions.lib)

target_link_libraries(MORPH_Server
                      MORPH_Shared_Functions 
                      sfml-system
                      sfml-network
                      )

target_include_directories(MORPH_Server 
                           PRIVATE C:/Users/dylan/Desktop/MORPH/MORPH_Shared_Functions
                           PRIVATE C:/libraries/SFML/SFML-2.5.1/include
                           PRIVATE C:/libraries/GLM/glm
                           PRIVATE C:/libraries/CEREAL
                           )
```

Comment: You probably want to start with removing `set(SFML_DIR "C:/libraries/SFML/SFMLx64SourceAndCompile")` and the other parts where c:/ is used.

Comment: By replacing them with paths on a Linux system? So the only way I can compile my projects for Linux is actually executing cmake ON Linux? I can't do this from windows as I requested?

Comment: You're asking for **cross-compilation**. That has very little to do with CMake... you will need a cross-compiler setup.

Comment: One way you can do this on windows is to use WSL, although then you are still doing it on linux.

Comment: Here is some info on crosscompiling: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17019788/cross-platform-build-under-windows-targeting-linux-using-cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17019788/cross-platform-build-under-windows-targeting-linux-using-cmake)

Comment: Generally speaking, it's not really worth the trouble. Cross-compiler setups are tricky buggers. If you want to play it clean, you'll need a Linux machine (or a dual boot, or a VM) to *test* your binaries on anyway, so why not use that for building as well? *Much* fewer headaches that way.

Comment: This may help for a WSL setup: [https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c-with-visual-studio-2019-and-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl/](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c-with-visual-studio-2019-and-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl/)

Comment: I do agree that the cross-compiling is not an easy setup.

Comment: So if I'm correct, compiling for Linux, from Windows, would be called "cross-compiling", and some of you think it's hard.

Alternatively, what about if I just pull the project from each OS I want to build it on on, and adapt CMakeLists.txt so it runs diferently on each OS? Using conditionals for OS checking, for example: "if(WIN32)" -> check these directories.

Comment: With `CMake` the preferred approach is not to hard code any directories at all in the `CMakeLists.txt`. Instead have `CMake` find the correct folder for you.  On windows this is more difficult because there is no standard locations for library files or include directories like there are for POSIX systems however you can use a combination of CMake's find commands and also environment variables.

Comment: You can pass directories to CMake via command line, e.g. `-DSFML_DIR="C:/libraries/SFML/SFMLx64SourceAndCompile"`. That is generally preferred over hardcoding paths in `CMakeLists.txt`. (And usually required only on Windows, which does not have default folders for such installations, and Linux if you're using non-standard installation paths.)

Answer (score 2):

You are lucky as both the three libraries you use export their packages correctly.

On linux, I will assume that the libraries are installed in `~/workspace/libraries`.

The trick will be to use `find_package` for all your dependencies, and you must drop every custom `Findxyz.cmake` files.

Then, you will have to drop the ALL_CAPS for the directory name. This is important for CMake to find the packages correctly. On windows it may not matter as the filesystem is not case sensitive, but on linux it is.

So first, to make your CMakeLists completely agnostic on where to find the packages, we will create a new file called `linux-dependencies.cmake` with this content:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "$ENV{HOME}/workspace/libraries")
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "path/to/morph/build") # can be relative
```

And `windows-dependencies.cmake`:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:/libraries/")
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "$ENV{HOMEPATH}/Desktop/MORPH/build")
```

Of course, if you set the library installation directory relative to the project or on both platform relative to the home directory, you can have only one `dependencies.cmake` file.

Then, on your next cmake invocation, simply tell cmake to include that file:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_PROJECT_INCLUDE=linux-dependencies.cmake
```

Note that `CMAKE_PROJECT_INCLUDE` is only available since CMake 3.15. If you don't want to upgrade CMake or simply to provide a default, you can always include the file manually.

You CMakeLists file should look like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

project(MORPH_Server VERSION 1.0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

configure_file(CmakeConfig.h.in CmakeConfig.h)

find_package(SFML 2.5.1 COMPONENTS system network REQUIRED)
find_package(glm 0.9.9 REQUIRED)
find_package(cereal REQUIRED) # cereal don't export version info as far as I know

# You will have to export your target or write a MORPH-config.cmake file
find_package(MORPH REQUIRED)

add_executable(MORPH_Server)
target_sources(MORPH_Server
               PRIVATE Main.cpp 
               PRIVATE Game.cpp
               PRIVATE CommandManager.cpp
               PRIVATE ServerPlayer.cpp
               PRIVATE ServerProp.cpp
               PRIVATE ServerWorldState.cpp
               PRIVATE UDP_Server_CS.cpp
               )

# this take care of both linking and include dirs
target_link_libraries(MORPH_Server
                      MORPH_Shared_Functions 
                      sfml-system
                      sfml-network
                      glm
                      cereal
                      )
```

Another thing that can help: set the same `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` as `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` or `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX/libname` when installing libraries.

---

If you want to compile the linux executable on windows, I would advise to simply use WSL or to run the compiler inside Docker. VSCode actually has a nice extension to use a docker as a build environment, and as far as I know, can also use WSL as a build and run environment.

Comment: "Then, you will have to drop the ALL_CAPS for the directory name. This is important for CMake to find the packages correctly." - First time hear about this CMake constraint. Why it is important to not have directories named in uppercase?

Comment: @Tsyvarev this is because the package name (the name of the direcories inside `share/cmake` and the `xyz-config.cmake` file) have a case defined by the library. If you put the installation directory in a prefix that don't correspond to the package name and set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to the parent directory, it won't search in those.

Comment: So if we have the prefix path to `/install/` and inside have installed libraries in separated prefixes like `/install/glm` `/install/cereal` CMake will search in those. But making them all caps will make them technically different directory names on linux.

Answer (score 1):

my 2 cents,

### 1

According to the `find_package()` search procedure documentation:

> In all cases the `<name>` is treated as case-insensitive and corresponds to any of the names specified (`<PackageName>` or names given by `NAMES`).

ref: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#search-procedure

note: personally I prefer to use `PackageNameConfig.cmake` than `package-name-config.cmake` ...

### 2

Why not simply add the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` on the configure command line than passing by your `dependencies.cmake` files ?

### 3

For static linking, I would use a `FetchContent()` approach to control the "static-ness" since most of Linux distro will tend to build libraries as shared then put them in directories following the [FHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard).

#### 3.1

You can also use flag to allow user to use system-wide libraries if they want (thus distro maintainers are happy as well as you can create a standalone artifact easily).
warning: Most libraries are not intended to be used inside a super build so you may need to patch them (i.e. `PATCH_COMMAND git apply ...`)

```
# enable CMP0077 so superbuild can set it.
option(BUILD_THIRDPARTY "Build the third party" ON)
...
# to allow recursive superbuild (add_subdirectory(morph_server) etc...) 
# first check if third party target is not already present
# see: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/17735
if(NOT TARGET ThirdParty::ThirdParty)
  if(BUILD_THIRDPARTY)
   FetchContent_Declare(...)
   set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF)
   set(BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF) ...
   FetchContent_MakeAvailable(third_party)
   set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ${BUILD_SHARED_BCKP})
  else()
    find_package(ThirdParty REQUIRED)
  endif()
endif()
```

### 4

You may also provide a default `FindThirdParty.cmake`.

```
if(UNIX)
  list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "$ENV{HOME}/workspace/libraries")
  list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "path/to/morph/build") # can be relative
else()
  list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:/libraries/")
  list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "$ENV{HOMEPATH}/Desktop/MORPH/build")
endif()

find_package(ThirdParty CONFIG REQUIRED)
```

So you don't have to play with `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` or `dependencies.cmake` etc. and users can still provide their own `FindThirdParty.cmake` and prepend the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` if they want to change...